# Best statistical test for comparing pre and post intervention (but the intervention happens repeatedly?)

Tags: t-test, intervention-analysis

The intervention: before each new appointment with a student the guidance counsellor is reminded to consult with the student about proper information on contraceptives.

The control group measures how often the guidance counsellor consults with students about contraceptives without any reminders.

I was going to do tests that compare the pre and post intervention as independent groups but I'm worried for example if the counsellor has multiple appointments a day, because he is getting a new reminder with each appointment, by the 7th appointment of the day he might be influenced to consult with the student even without the reminder because he's already received the reminder 6 times with previous appointments. Is there a statistical test that accounts for that?